# How do i play 1 audio file and playback them to 2 different speakers?

Tags: windows-10, audio, vlc-media-player, speakers

I want to play a chill music beat, one for my default speaker and one for my mic input ( the devices are in the same computer ). How do I playback audio to 2 speakers on the same computer with VLC?

I'm using Windows 10, Thanks for helping!

Comment: I don't use Windows, so I've no experience with any of these, but here's a list of audio routing software for Win, based on searching alternatives to  the Mac's  Loopback - https://alternativeto.net/software/loopback/?platform=windows

Comment: Kindly check if this can help you: [How to play sound on two devices at once in Windows 10](https://windowsreport.com/play-sound-2-devices-windows-10/)